# Django-heroku install failure

Tags: python, django, macos, heroku

I am operating a django site from a mac catalina. It is working perfectly, except for the fact that I can't use python manage.py runserver. Pretty big problems, right? I have learned that you have to install django-heroku. I have tried that, but it doesn't work with this computer. To get around this, I installed something called heroku-toolkit. It works for pushing code to Heroku, but I can't runserver or collecstatic! Here is the error I get when I run pip3 install django-heroku:

```
Collecting django-heroku
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/af/5475a876c5addd5a3494db47d9f7be93cc14d3a7603542b194572791b6c6/django_heroku-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: django in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django-heroku) (3.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: whitenoise in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django-heroku) (5.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: dj-database-url>=0.5.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django-heroku) (0.5.0)
Collecting psycopg2 (from django-heroku)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a8/8f/1c5690eebf148d1d1554fc00ccf9101e134636553dbb75bdfef4f85d7647/psycopg2-2.8.5.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref~=3.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django->django-heroku) (3.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django->django-heroku) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from django->django-heroku) (2020.1)
Installing collected packages: psycopg2, django-heroku
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/k8/4qqdxbkn1l31ctsjbgpngr_00000gn/T/pip-install-u8ftbfmm/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/k8/4qqdxbkn1l31ctsjbgpngr_00000gn/T/pip-install-u8ftbfmm/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/k8/4qqdxbkn1l31ctsjbgpngr_00000gn/T/pip-record-_tusvgi7/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/var/folders/k8/4qqdxbkn1l31ctsjbgpngr_00000gn/T/pip-install-u8ftbfmm/psycopg2/
    Complete output (151 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/green.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/pqpath.o
    psycopg/pqpath.c:138:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                    PQstatus(conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(*pgres)));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    psycopg/pqpath.c:1717:11: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
        ret = 1;
              ^
    psycopg/pqpath.c:1822:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                    PQstatus(curs->conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(curs->pgres)));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    3 warnings generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/utils.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/bytes_format.o
    In file included from psycopg/bytes_format.c:82:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/libpq_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/libpq_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/libpq_support.c:30:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/win32_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/win32_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/win32_support.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/solaris_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/solaris_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/solaris_support.c:29:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/aix_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/aix_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/aix_support.c:29:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/connection_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/connection_int.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/connection_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/connection_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/cursor_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/cursor_int.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/cursor_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/cursor_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/column_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/column_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/column_type.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/replication_connection_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/replication_connection_type.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/replication_cursor_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/replication_message_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_message_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/replication_message_type.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/diagnostics_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/diagnostics_type.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/error_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/error_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/error_type.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/conninfo_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/conninfo_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/conninfo_type.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/lobject_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/lobject_int.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/lobject_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/lobject_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/notify_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/notify_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/notify_type.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/xid_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/xid_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_asis.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_binary.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_binary.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_datetime.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_list.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_list.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pboolean.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pint.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pint.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pfloat.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_qstring.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/microprotocols.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/microprotocols.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o
    In file included from psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120003 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/typecast.o
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/libpq_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/win32_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/solaris_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/aix_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/column_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/replication_message_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/conninfo_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/k8/4qqdxbkn1l31ctsjbgpngr_00000gn/T/pip-install-u8ftbfmm/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/k8/4qqdxbkn1l31ctsjbgpngr_00000gn/T/pip-install-u8ftbfmm/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/k8/4qqdxbkn1l31ctsjbgpngr_00000gn/T/pip-record-_tusvgi7/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

When I run Python3 manage.py runserver it says that there is no module named django-heroku. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue since I have macos catalina too.

first, check if you are in the right directory when you deploy. You have to be at `root` directory.

second, try this command: `pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.4` and see whether it works. As `psycopg2` seems not working on mac.

Comment: I used pip3 install psycopg2-binary==2.8.5, then tried to install django-heroku. It didn't work again. Can you help?

Comment: What do you mean, root directory?

Comment: You have to see if you are within the main folder when you are deploying. So, if you are in a folder before or after the root, the deployment wont work. Also, check if your procfile is proper configured with the following config: `web: gunicorn your_app_root_folder.wsgi`.

Comment: Yes, the Procfile has that. Should I have the venv on or off?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to install something called django-on-heroku. It is the new updated version of django-heroku